# Fade cards with scrolling - angular (I accept library suggestions)

Tags: css, angular, animation, angular-animations

I would like the cards to appear on the screen during scrolling. I do not know very well about angular animation, but I used it for now

**html:**

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="posts">
  <div id="feed-{{post.id}}" (click)="getFeed(post)" *ngFor="let post of posts | conteudoFilter:nivel; " [@scrollAnimation]="state" 
  class="feed card col s12" >
  <img src="{{post.thumb}}" alt="" class="responsive-img">
  <!-- <div class="">{{post.descricao | titlecase}}</div> -->
</div>
</div>

<app-video *ngIf="currentVideo" [currentVideo]="currentVideo"></app-video>
<app-imgdisplay ></app-imgdisplay>
```

**ts**

```
export class FeedComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(VideoComponent) videoComp:VideoComponent;
  @ViewChild(ImgdisplayComponent) imgDisplay:ImgdisplayComponent;

  state = 'hide'

 public posts:Conteudo[];
 public nivel:{};
 public currentVideo;
 public currentImg: string;

  constructor(public auth:AuthService, public database:DatabaseService<Conteudo>, public router:Router, public el: ElementRef ) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ok");
    if(this.auth.User.nivel){
      this.nivel = {nivel:this.auth.User.nivel};
      this.database.listValues("CONTEUDO").subscribe(result => this.posts = result);
    }
  }

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  checkScroll() {
    const componentPosition = this.el.nativeElement.offsetTop
    const scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset

    if (scrollPosition >= componentPosition) {
      this.state = 'show'
    } else {
      this.state = 'hide'
    }

  }
```

The transition I applied is not working as I wanted, scrolling the page, all cards appear at the same time, but I wanted the effect to be applied to each card individually as it appears on the screen

I believe the problem is in my by, I already tried to switch to another div and I could not. If someone wants to give some library management to make animation, feel free to give example of the chosen library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is couple option to achieve this effect. First, to the component add:

```js
@Component({
  ..
  animations: [rowsAnimation],
})
```

Then create this fade in animation with move from left to right.

```js
import { trigger, sequence, animate, transition, style } from '@angular/animations';

export const rowsAnimation =   trigger('rowsAnimation', [
    transition('void => *', [
      style({ 'height': '*', 'opacity': '0', 'transform': 'translateX(-550px)', 'box-shadow': 'none' }),
      sequence([
        animate('.35s ease', style({
          'height': '*',
          'opacity': '.2',
          'transform': 'translateX(0)',
          'box-shadow': 'none',
        })),
        animate('.35s ease', style({
          height: '*',
          opacity: 1,
          transform: 'translateX(0)',
        })),
      ]),
    ])
]);
```

Then add to the html the animation.

```
<div class="row"
     *ngIf="posts">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let post of posts | conteudoFilter:nivel; ">
        <div id="feed-{{post.id}}"
             (click)="getFeed(post)"
             [@rowsAnimation]=""
             class="feed card col s12">
            <img src="{{post.thumb}}" alt="" class="responsive-img">
            <!-- <div class="">{{post.descricao | titlecase}}</div> -->
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Animation is set to `void => *`, it means it will appear when new row is added to the DOM.
The last step is to add these rows one by one. Below just simple example if animation works:

```
addRow() {
  this.posts.push({id: 1});
}
```

Animation should appear. Then you need to trigger it in the scroll.